# Set a click-event to a element which is added by this event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a click-event to a element, which is added by the same script/event?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="example"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.example').click(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="example"></div>');
});
```

So the new div-elements should also be 'clickable' to set new elements. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you heard of event delegation? Research on that, it will be a good start ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use EventDeletagation:

```
$('body').on('click', '.example', function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="example"></div>');
});
```

Comment: It happens because when you use "click" for binding, it searchs the elements for the objects you are targeting in the page.
As you are creating new elements, you need to put the responsability in something that had been created before them, in this case it was the body - it looks for every click in elements with the example class, as I understand it.